# Error: contains a blank line while attempting to Clean and rebuild in R

Tags: r, devtools

I'm trying to create a package. Whenever, I try to 'Clean and rebuild' I'm getting the following error

```
==> devtools::document(roclets=c('rd', 'collate', 'namespace'))
Loading mypackage
Error: contains a blank line
Execution halted

Exited with status 1.
```

Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Making sure to restart the R Session and leaving NO blank lines in between in the 'DESCRIPTION' file solves the problem.